# How to get a Monero Transaction Hash to check incoming deposit on MoneroAddress.org generated address - without CLI or GUI wallet?

Tags: transaction-data

I need some help with following!

I have set up a monero address with moneroaddress.org.

I want to be able to check if that address has received a monero payment using any available online tools / websites.

I **do not** want to use Monero Wallet CLI or GUI.

- I have my moneroaddress.org Public Address

  I have my moneroaddress.org Mnemonic seed

  I have my moneroaddress.org Spend Key

  I have my moneroaddress.org View Key

I have a couple of questions:

Apart from the moneroaddress.org generated monero Public Address, what other data/information do I need to confirm the transaction has been completed by using any of the online / website tools available?

Where can I go / is it possible to confirm Monreo has been deposited to my moneroaddress.org generated monero address without having a Monero CLI or GUI wallet and / or without creating a view only wallet with CLI or GUI?

I know about mymonero.org, but if i do not have any monero in the wallet to pay the importation fee - how can i complete the import?

What is the Transaction Hash and how do I create one / get one for my transaction i.e. where I receive a monero deposit to my moneroaddress.org address

Any other useful / relevant information (i.e. relevant but not asked above) will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A transaction hash is a way of uniquely identifying a transaction.

If you have a transaction hash, you can use xmrchain.net to locate and examine the transaction, and then decrypt it to see the amount of incoming funds and verify those funds were destined for your wallet address. Here is an example transaction, where you can enter your Monero address and private view key to decrypt it: https://xmrchain.net/tx/f733590f7c139d512be0237f81e420a1ad07b19f264e74ad2c599606e61b5a6d

There are only two ways to determine the transaction hash for an incoming transaction. Either the person that sent you the funds tells you the hash, or you need to scan every transaction on the blockchain to check if any of them are destined for you.

Therefore if you aren't told the transaction hash, you're going to need to use some kind of wallet software that can scan the blockchain. You may not want to use the official Monero CLI or GUI, and may not be able to use mymonero.org, but you're going to have to use some kind of wallet. I don't know of any other trustworthy mymonero.org alternative, which means you'll have to download and install some other kind of Monero wallet software. If you're going to have to do that, you might as well use the official Monero GUI or CLI.

If the reason you don't want to download and install software is because you don't want to download the entire blockchain, then you can install the Monero GUI and connect to a remote node. You can find a list of remote nodes here: https://moneroworld.com/#nodes This means you won't have to download the entire blockchain, and your wallet will instead simply scan the blockchain for transactions destined for you.

Comment: Hi knacc, Thanks for the reply. How does the sender determine/create a transaction hash. Can they do it themselves i.e. make it up or is it created by the 'monero' process. Could I specify / choose a transaction hash for the sender to use?

Comment: @plannter The transaction hash is like a "fingerprint" of the transaction, and depends on the specific outputs that the sender's wallet decides to spend. This means you can't tell the sender a hash to use in advance. The sender can only tell it to you after they create the transaction. The transaction hash, which is sometimes also called the transaction id, will be listed next to the transaction in the history section of the sender's wallet, and they will easily be able to provide it to you.